# Determining the number of simulations in non-parametric classification simulation

Tags: classification, nonparametric, simulation

I am currently working on setting up a simulation study that compares the effectiveness of k-nearest neighbours and gradient boosted trees.

I have checked these two sources. Both refer to p-values and parameter estimates as basis for calculating the number of simulations needed. Since the models I want to test have neither, this is problematic. 
https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22number+of+simulations%22+non-parametric
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.2673

I wonder if there is an alternate approach to base the number of simulations on. Or maybe a special framework for this type of simulation.

edit as requested: 
I plan to compare these by several measures.

[image: Confusion matrix]

Positive predictive value $ = \frac{ TruePositive}{ TruePositive + FalsePositive} = \frac{True Positive}{Total Predicted Positive}$

Negative predictive value $= \frac{TrueNegative}{ FalseNegative + FalseNegative } =      \frac{TrueNegative}{ Total Predicted Positive }$

True Positive Rate or Sensitivity = $\frac{TruePositive}{ TruePositive + FalseNegative } = \frac{TruePositive}{Total Observed Positive}$

True Negative Rate or Specificity = $\frac{TrueNegative}{ TrueNegative + FalsePositive } = \frac{TrueNegative}{Total Observed Negative}$

Misclassification Rate = $\frac{FalsePositive + FalseNegative}{Total}$

These measures are all related in someway to how well the models classify the data to the "true" classifications. It is how close the model comes to that truth that I plan to define as effective.

Comment: It depends *strongly* on how "effectiveness" is measured, on how you plan to compare it (whether quantitatively, visually, or in some other way), and on how you characterize the domain to which these methods might be applied.  Could you edit this post to elaborate on your needs?